# Skipping to specific time in HTML5 audio element without loading the complete file

Tags: javascript, html, audio, youtube

I want to know if it's possible to play music with the HTML5 `audio` tag at a specific time without loading all the data beforehand: so the music can start directly and not wait for a full download before playing (like Youtube does when you jump in the video file).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, I think it does this out of the box (at least in Firefox).

The Mozilla Developer Network offers a [pretty good tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges) that should help you in the right direction.  If you're interested in skipping around programatically, the tutorial shows how this can be done using Javascript.

They also offer a really cool visualization of how the `<audio>` element buffers data [here](http://jsbin.com/memazaro/1/edit?html,output).  The red bars beneath the audio player show which blocks of data have been downloaded.  If you skip around, it'll become evident that there's gaps of unloaded audio data between segments of the song that you didn't listen to yet  (shown in grey).

The JSBin doesn't work in Chrome, but it will work in Firefox.  Here's the code from the link:

```
<p>
  <audio id="my-audio" controls>
    <source src="http://jPlayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="http://jPlayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  </audio>
</p>
<p>
  <canvas id="my-canvas" width="300" height="20">
  </canvas>
</p>
<script>
  window.onload = function(){ 

    var myAudio = document.getElementById('my-audio');
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
    var context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

    context.fillStyle = 'lightgray';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, 20);
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.strokeStyle = 'white';

    var inc = myCanvas.width / myAudio.duration;

    // display TimeRanges

    myAudio.addEventListener('seeked', function() {
      for (i = 0; i < myAudio.buffered.length; i++) {

        var startX = myAudio.buffered.start(i) * inc;
        var endX = myAudio.buffered.end(i) * inc;

        context.fillRect(startX, 0, endX, 20);
        context.rect(startX, 0, endX, 20);
        context.stroke();
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```